# Trouble with combinatoric logic problem with liars and truthtellers

Tags: combinatorics, logic

Nine people are seated around a circular table, and each person has the status of being a
truth-teller (who always tells the truth) or a liar (who always lies). Furthermore, each person knows
the status of the person sitting to their left. When asked about the status of the person sitting to
their left, five people say that the person is a truth-teller and four people say that the person is a
liar. How many different ways can the status of each person be assigned so that this occurs?

I set truthtellers as "T" and liars as "L." Then, I realized the ways we could get a supposed liar or a truthteller. If we have TL, the truthteller will come out to an L. If we have LT, the liar will come out to a T. If we have LL, the liar will become a T. If we have TT, the truthteller will become a T. So, to get 4 liars and 5 truthtellers, I realized I need to put together a string of TLTLT, LTLTL, LLLL and TTTT (notice the first person also kinda acts as the last person of the round table. I am stuck here, but i feel like it reduces to case work such as TLTLT + TTTT, then T+TLTLT + TTT, and with this reasoning for the other cases i got 4x5=20.

My problem: I definitely went wrong somewhere but can't work out what.

Comment: I suggest: wrote out some valid settings, then look for patterns.  Is the correct number of liars determined by the rules?  Are there, instead, some very different valid settings?

Comment: Note:  it may help to remark that switching each persons status preserves the number of claimed truth-tellers and the number of liars.

Comment: The answer of each person indicates whether the person to their left shares the same status: for TT and LL the answer is T, while for TL and LT the answer is L. Round the table, $4$ people answered L, so there are 4 status switches between neighbours.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by status switches? Like when a truth teller becomes a liar or something?

Comment: For your example, (person 1) TTLTLTTTT (person 9, and loop). Person 3 has the different status (L) from the person on their left (T), which I called a status switch. Person 7 has the same status as the person on their left (T), which is not a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two types of 9 character strings...

- A claim string consisting of the characters S and D

  - an S in position $n$ means that person $n$ has claimed the the person to their left is a truth teller (S for "same")
  - a D in position $n$ means that person $n$ has claimed the the person to their left is a liar (D for "different")
- A status string consisting of the characters T and L indicating whether person $n$ is a truth teller or a liar

The crucial thing to realize is that every Claim string corresponds to exactly 2 status strings.

e.g. the claim string...

```
S S D S D D S D S
```

can result from exactly 2 status strings...

```
T T T L L T L L T
```

and

```
L L L T T L T T L
```

So the number of Status strings is just double the number of Claim strings...
$$N = 2 \binom 94 = 252$$

It is worth mentioning that the number of people claiming their neighbour is a liar must be an even number (in this case 4)